# Mongoose error while sorting $text search scores

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing a simple text search using Mongoose and MongoDB. I have a model called Todo, and I'm searching through my collection that has been indexed. For example, I'm trying to do a text search of the word "coffee" in the line below.

```
Todo.find( 
    { $text: { $search: "coffee" }}, 
    { score: { "$meta": "textScore" }})
.sort( { score: { "$meta": "textScore" }})
.limit(20);
```

This causes the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid sort value: {score: [object Object] }
```

The error points to the line that I put in above. I'm certain it's the sorting method that's causing issues, because when I remove that part of the query, I'm able to get my unsorted results.

The thing that makes this issue even more perplexing is that I run the exact same query through robomongo in the same collection, and it works there.

```
db.todos.find( 
    {$text: { $search: "coffee" }}, 
    {score: { "$meta": "textScore" }})
.sort({score: { "$meta": "textScore" }})
.limit(20);
```

This is the exact same documentation provided by MongoDB as well. I'm fairly certain it's an issue with Mongoose, but it was working previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was an error with the Mongoose version. I was using 3.6, after upgrading to 4.4.20 it started working.